# The program does not executes after m+=z. Why is this happeing?

Tags: python, list

Consider the code below:

```py
a = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89]
k = len(a)
i = 0
m = []
while i < k:
      if a[i] < 5:
          z = a[i]
          m += z
          i += 1
      else:
          break

print(m)
```

When I am trying to execute it, I get:

> m += z
>
> TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Why is that?

Comment: Please include the precise error you are experiencing in your question. (I assume it is a `TypeError` about `z` not being iterate).

Comment: Welcome to SO. A couple of pointers to help you get good answers to good questions. 1) Take [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) - you'll get your first badge! 2) When asking a question, make sure to explain what you're trying to achieve, as @Brian says, give accurate details of the problem that you're having and make sure you tag the language you're using. By not tagging (I assume) Python with your question, a lot of people who might be able to help you won't see your question at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`m` is a `list`; the `+=` operator for it expects another iterable to add the items from one at a time (so `+= [1, 2, 3]` adds three items, not a single `list`, to the `list`), not a single item to add.

`x` is an `int`, so this doesn't work. You likely want:

```
m.append(x)
```

This would also work:

```
m += [x]
```

but using `append` is clearer (and last I checked, slightly faster).

Comment: How do you know whether a command is faster or not than the other. I am a beginner to both python and SO, i do need a bit of clarification.

Comment: @nik: Mostly I use `%%timeit` magic for microbenchmarks in `ipython`. You can use the `timeit` module directly. For example, I just ran a test with `%%timeit` with no setup, and a body of `m = []`, `for i in (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10):`, and then either `m += [i]`, `m.append(i)` or `m += i,` (that last one uses a one-`tuple` instead of a one-element `list`, to compare the expense of making the `list` to making the `tuple`). `append` won with 518 ns per loop; `+= i,` was only slightly slower, 527 ns per loop, and `+= [i]` was the slowest, 660 ns per loop.